# Definition of Linkage Desiquilibrium (LD)

Tags: evolution, natural-selection, mathematical-models, population-dynamics, population-genetics

According to [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linkage_disequilibrium), linkage disequilibrium $D$ equals

$$D = x_{11} - p_1\cdot q_1$$

where:

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        \text{Haplotype} & \text{Frequency}\\
        A_1B_1 & x_{11}\\
        A_{1}B_{2} & x_{12} \\
        A_{2}B_{1} & x_{21} \\
        A_{2}B_{2} & x_{22} \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

and

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        \text{Allele} & \text{Frequency}\\
    A_{1} & p_{1}=x_{11}+x_{12} \\
    A_{2} & p_{2}=x_{21}+x_{22} \\
    B_{1} & q_{1}=x_{11}+x_{21} \\
    B_{2} & q_{2}=x_{12}+x_{22} \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

According to [Hartl and Clark](http://books.google.ca/books/about/Principles_of_Population_Genetics.html?id=4ypuQgAACAAJ&redir_esc=y), linkage disequilibrium $D$ equals:

$$D = x_{11}x_{22}-x_{12}x_{21}$$

**Question**

Can you please prove that these two formulations of linkage disequilibrium are equivalent (assuming that they are equivalent)? If they're not… Do we use different definitions? What are their respective meanings?

Comment: none of your references seem to have links?

Comment: Yeah, where are the links?

Comment: Thanks for noticing. don't know what happened to them. I added the links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just need to solve the equation. p1 = X11 + X12; q1 = X11 + X21; 1 = X11 + X12 + X21 + X22.

D = X11 - (X11 + X12) * (X11 + X21)

D = X11 - (X11X11 + X11X21 + X11X12 + X12X21)

D = X11 - X11X11 - X11X21 - X11X12 - X12X21

D = X11 * (1 - X11) - X11X21 - X11X12 - X12X21

D = X11 * (X11 + X12 + X21 + X22 - X11) - X11X21 - X11X12 - X12X21

D = X11 * (X12 + X21 + X22) - X11X21 - X11X12 - X12X21

D = X11X12 + X11X21 + X11X22 - X11X21 - X11X12 - X12X21

D = X11X22 - X12X21

Sorry for the very long answer, but I thought it would be more clear if I wrote everything out.